# Microsoft Bot Framework: How to add Bot to chat via messaging extension?

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

Let's assume a user chats with another user in a 1:1 chat. (Might also be a group chat.) The user adds a bot and continues to chat while the bot now adds value to the conversation.

We are searching for a way to make adding the bot to a chat as seamless as possible through a simple button click. It seems the closest we can get to a button is using a [messaging extension action command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions?tabs=dotnet#action-commands).

When the user invokes the messaging extension our backend service runs and can respond e.g. with a card. Now instead of a card is it possible to generate a response to **add a bot**? There are special responses e.g. for [authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/219034c6f3efb8cf6be1931a31f688d127a159b3/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.cs#L56). Is there a response telling the Teams client to add a bot?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Check following sample application which helps to add bot instantly: https://github.com/SubbaReddi/89.teams-just-in-time-installation

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru This looks interesting, thank you! Just to be sure: does this only _install_ the Teams app (containing the bot) for the user (in my case the app is already installed) or does this also _add the bot to the conversation_, making it a participant?

Comment: It adds bot to conversation.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT It's weird. I added the "justInTimeInstall"-enabled response card as demonstrated by above sample. In a 1:1 _chat_ the user can now choose the msging extension, the confirmation dialog for the bot pops up and after clicking "Continue" the bot is successfully added (although not shown as participant). Invoking the msging extension from the 1:1 _running call chat_ instead fails. After submitting the "Continue" dialog Teams just shows "Unable to reach app. Please try again.". But this cannot be true, b/c adding the app via the 1:1 _chat_ (not _call chat_) works. Unsupported in call?

Comment: With regard to my question using "justInTimeInstall" looks like the solution. So far I assumed that a 1:1 chat and a 1:1 chat in a running call behave the same. Unfortunately I need this in a running call so the bot can access the call roster. I will probably open a new question phrased specifically in this direction. @SubbaReddiTummuru So if you add your sample as answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIT installation of bot is an option here. You will be able to add bot to user conversation. Check following sample application which helps to add bot instantly: https://github.com/SubbaReddi/89.teams-just-in-time-installation